# Non-significant p-values for factor levels with only 0s in negative binomial glm using glm.nb() in R

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, negative-binomial-distribution, likelihood-ratio

I am trying to fit a negative binomial GLM to fish catch data with month of the year (factor) as my explanatory variable. I have selected the month with the greatest number of catches as my reference level and fitted the model using the `glm.nb()` function from the MASS package.

```
model1<-glm.nb(catch~month+offset(log(Duration_hours*NumberHooksDeployed)),
 catchdata)
```

Using `anova(model1)` shows that the factor `month` is significant and my pseudo $R^2$ is about 55%. The problem I have is that months with no catches at all have p-values greater than 0.05 (close to 1), even though I would expect them to be significantly lower than the reference level. Months with only very few catches are significant on the other hand. The output from the `predict()` function makes sense, so I think the model should be fine.
Is there a problem with the likelihood test R uses, or am I fitting the wrong model to my data? From other posts I figured that I might have to use a likelihood ratio rather than Wald's test; any suggestions on how to do that in R?
Any help would be greatly appreciated. See model output below, the months with 0 catches are May and June:

```
Call:
glm.nb(formula = NumCaught ~ factor(month) + offset(log(Effort_mins * 
Nhooks)), data = f[f$Area == "PW", ], init.theta = 1.181267049, 
link = log)

Deviance Residuals: 
Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-1.8445  -0.7766  -0.2148   0.0000   1.5386  

Coefficients:
                     Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)            -2.647e+00  3.192e-01  -8.292  < 2e-16 ***
factor(month)May       -2.754e+01  1.024e+05   0.000 0.999785    
factor(month)June      -2.790e+01  3.122e+05   0.000 0.999929    
factor(month)September -2.516e+00  6.516e-01  -3.861 0.000113 ***
factor(month)December  -1.112e-01  4.403e-01  -0.253 0.800543    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1 

(Dispersion parameter for Negative Binomial(1.1813) family taken to be 1)

Null deviance: 80.420  on 45  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 36.178  on 41  degrees of freedom
AIC: 140.81

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 1


          Theta:  1.181 
      Std. Err.:  0.525 

2 x log-likelihood:  -128.815
```

Comment: What is the reason for the offset()? Also the log of two things multiplied is going to be the logs of each, added. Is that what you wanted?

Comment: The offset is to account for differences in fishing effort for each sample (number of hooks used and the duration of the gear deployment)

Comment: Interesting. Can you share the data?

Comment: @Peter Flom. No unfortunately not and I don't think a subset would be of any use in this case.

Comment: I would look at the relationship between the offset and the number caught, and make sure the offset is doing the right thing.

Comment: @Peter Flom. Thanks a lot for your input. As I stated in the question, when I use predict() I get very sensible results and using the log() of a measure of catch effort as the offset is very common in the fisheries science literature so I don't think the offset is causing a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because your May and June dummy variables perfectly predict outcomes of zero.  The "true" MLEs for May and June would be negative infinity, but the log-likelihood increases at a slower and slower rate and eventually the optimizer gives up.  Since the log-likelihood is almost flat at the supposed MLE, the standard errors are estimated to be huge when they are really meaningless.  It is the equivalent of a separation problem in logistic regression.